# Excel: Comparar dos columnas

Tags: excel, formulas

Escribo ya que tengo una consulta sobre como hacer esto ya que he probado con BuscarV, contar y coincidir y no tengo resultados.

Supongamos por un momento que tengo dos columnas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver Existen valores que se repiten pero no estan en el mismo orden en ambas columnas, y lo que estoy tratando de construir es una formula que me indique los valores que existen en comun entre ambas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: qué intentaste con buscarv? Incluye tus intentos EN la pregunta, yendo a [edit] por favor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De entrada, una objeción: en tu salida de ejemplo, marcas NO en la primera fila de valores, pero si he entendido correctamente el enunciado de tus requisitos, debería marcar SI como todas las demás, porque el valor en B2 sí está presente en una celda de la columna A, concretamente la celda A3.

Es importante ser preciso en el enunciado de los requisitos.

La siguiente fórmula permite comprobar si hay alguna coincidencia entre los valores de cualquiera de las columnas, A ó B, con los valores de cualquier fila en la otra columna a lo largo de la tabla.

```swift
=SI(O(CONTAR.SI(B:B;A2)>0;CONTAR.SI(A:A;B2)>0);"SI";"NO")
```

Esta fórmula comprueba si el valor de A2 existe en alguna celda en todo el rango de la columna B (B:B) o si el valor de B2 existe en alguna celda de la columna A, empleando la función `O` para crear la disyunción lógica y la función `CONTAR.SI(rango,criterios)` para evaluar las coincidencias. La función `SI(prueba_lógica; valor_si_verdadero; [valor_si_falso])` envuelve las demás y se encarga de devolver el texto "SI" en caso de verificarse alguna coincidencia o devolver "NO" si no se encuentra ninguna.

Esta es la tabla de ejemplo que propones para someterla a prueba, ampliada, junto con el resultado de aplicar la fórmula en la columna `Coincidencia`:

```swift
+---------+---------+--------------+
| Valor_1 | Valor_2 | Coincidencia |
+---------+---------+--------------+
|  1.003  |     45  | SI           |
|  45     |     20  | SI           |
|  30     |     30  | SI           |
|  20     |      1  | SI           |
|  5      |      9  | NO           |
|  200    |     45  | SI           |
|  2.010  |     40  | NO           |
|  1.212  |     30  | SI           |
|  75     |     20  | SI           |
|  50     |     20  | SI           |
+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Si tus requisitos y objetivo son realizar la búsqueda de coincidencias únicamente del valor de A en todo el rango de filas de B, como podría deducirse de la salida de ejemplo que propones, entonces la fórmula adecuada y el resultado de su aplicación sobre la misma tabla serían los siguientes:

```swift
=SI(CONTAR.SI(B:B;A2)>0;"SI";"NO")
```

```swift
+---------+---------+--------------+
| Valor_1 | Valor_2 | Coincidencia |
+---------+---------+--------------+
|  1.003  |     45  | NO           |
|  45     |     20  | SI           |
|  30     |     30  | SI           |
|  20     |      1  | SI           |
|  5      |      9  | NO           |
|  200    |     45  | NO           |
|  2.010  |     40  | NO           |
|  1.212  |     30  | NO           |
|  75     |     20  | NO           |
|  50     |     20  | NO           |
+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Muchas gracias y dicsulpa por mi error en el enunciado